# Header(ion-nav-bar) and view part(ion-nav-view) transition are separate in ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on ionic application and I want transition of header with ion-nav-view.

Currently Header is fixed and only View part is moving. 
Is there any way to achieve it?

...

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 two-side" align-title="center"> .... </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="content">
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: can you paste your index.html code

Comment: inlcude your header part in ion-view.. not in index.html.. then transition of header works